# Reindexing Pandas Timeseries by group

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

So what I'm trying to do is reindex a DataFrame that has a bunch of separate groups within the frame. Each one has it's own index that I'd like to add a End of Month index into. I think an example is best:

Given this DataFrame:

```
In [72]: a = {'2014-01-02': {'A': 1}, '2014-02-03': {'A': 1}, '2014-03-05': {'A': 1}}

In [74]: b = {'2015-01-02': {'A': 2}, '2015-02-03': {'A': 2}, '2015-03-05': {'A': 2}}
In [76]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a,orient='index').append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(b,orient='index'))
Out[76]:
            A
2014-01-02  1
2014-02-03  1
2014-03-05  1
2015-01-02  2
2015-02-03  2
2015-03-05  2
```

(Note the 2014 vs 2015)

I want to take the two groups in the 'A' column, and reindex each to include month ends for each group from the min until the month end after the max of the index. I would want an output like so:

```
            A
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-31  1
2014-02-03  1
2014-02-28  1
2014-03-05  1
2014-03-31  1
2015-01-02  2
2015-01-31  2
2015-02-03  2
2015-02-28  2
2015-03-05  2
2015-03-31  2
```

Comment: You'll want to use a "multi-index" on your dataframe. Looking at "multi-index" in pandas documentation will be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [59]:
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index , format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df
Out[59]:
            A
2014-01-02  1
2014-02-03  1
2014-03-05  1
2015-01-02  2
2015-02-03  2
2015-03-05  2

In [61]:
month_end = df.resample('M').dropna()
month_end
Out[61]:
            A
2014-01-31  1
2014-02-28  1
2014-03-31  1
2015-01-31  2
2015-02-28  2
2015-03-31  2

In [64]:
pd.concat([df , month_end]).sortlevel(0)
Out[64]:
            A
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-31  1
2014-02-03  1
2014-02-28  1
2014-03-05  1
2014-03-31  1
2015-01-02  2
2015-01-31  2
2015-02-03  2
2015-02-28  2
2015-03-05  2
2015-03-31  2
```

Comment: I accepted this but also ran into a problem. If you have two in the same month, now the mean of A is used. Is there a way to make it make two entries, one for 1 and one for 2 in this scenario?

Comment: what do you mean by `if you have two in the same month` ?

Comment: If A == 1 has 2015-02-04 and A == 2 has 2015-02-05 in the index

Answer (score 0):

First, giving your dataframe an alias

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a,orient='index').append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(b,orient='index'))
```

Next, reset row names to index

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Now, check your dataframe's indexes

```
list(df.columns.values)
```

This is now multi-indexed, so that "A" is an index and aggregation functions will operate with respect to that additional index level.